# measurable subset of possibly non-measurable set.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a Polish space. Let $T$ be a possibly uncountable set of Borel probability measures on $X$.
Suppose there exists a subset $A$ of $X$ with the following property:
For each $\mu\in T$, there exists a measurable subset of $A$, $S_{\mu}\subset A$, such that $\mu(S_{\mu})=1$.

Question:Does there exist a measurable subset $S$ of $A$ such that
$\mu(S)=1$ for all $\mu\in T$?

Comment: If $\mu$ is an element of the subset $A$ of $X$, what would $\mu(S_\mu)$ mean?  Are you using $\mu$ to mean two different things here?

Comment: Sorry, my typo. $\mu$ is a measure that comes from the set $T$.

Comment: So, if $T$ is countable, we can simply take $S=\cup_{\mu\in T}S_{\mu}$, but when $T$ is uncountable then this step is a bit tricky to me.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be any non-measurable set and $T=\{\delta_x: x\in A\}$.
Then the hoped-for measurable set $S$ does not exist.